# LabWindows temporary files that can be ignored for version control

Tags: version-control, labwindows

I adding an older LabWindows project to version control. What is the temporary files that I can ignore for version control perpuses. I assume all the `*.niobj` and `.cdb` files can be ignored as they will be recreated from the source? Any other files?

I am using LabWindows/CVI version 7.0 to support legacy hardware but I assume the underling files is still the same for newer versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old question, but the answer is still good to know.

**Files to put under version control:**
.prj, .uir, .tui (you should add auto generation of those in the user interface editor as .uir are useless for version control), 
.ico, .png, .jpg, .gif, etc...

**Debatable whether or not to put under version control:**
.cws (workspace file including the various prj file, it changes at every use but it's good to have it the very first time after a git clone)

**Files to NOT put under version control:**
.cds (debug), .dbs,
.lib, .exe, .obj, .S...

Comment: You can also ignore all generated default folders under your project e.g. `cvibuild`

Comment: I think it is okay to keep the CDS (CVI Distribution Settings) file since it keeps the info about how to set up the installation build. It is quite tedious to keep creating this file on a fresh clone if it is not put under version control. I also notice that if the CDS created from the previous Labwindows/CVI IDE version is not compatible with the latest IDE version, the IDE can ask the user to upgrade it to the latest format. I can also manipulate the GUID info stored in this file to create a different manifest.

Comment: On the C dynamic library (the LIB and its accompanying DLL and C header for Windows and SO for Linux) files: if the dynamic library files come from a third-party and are needed in the project/CDS setup and they are not available from other external resources (GitHub, etc.), it is better to keep them in the version control.